# Apparently, my MySQL table is corrupt

Tags: mysql, database, corrupt

I use 000Webhost.

I've just created a table in my MySQL database.

I've got this error:

"Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 20, found 16. The table is probably corrupted".

My other tables work fine.

Why does just this table not work?

Connor

Comment: Can we see the table structure + sql request?

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.tillett.info/2012/02/17/mysql-problem-column-count-of-mysql-proc-is-wrong-expected-20-found-16-the-table-is-probably-corrupted/ Was the version of MySQL recently updated?

Comment: My table structure is as follows:

id|name|username|password|email

My query is in a function of a class, accessed by $user->login;

My query is below:

$login=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password=hashNew('$password')") or die(mysql_error());

hashNew is a function I've written, and $username and $password are paramters from my function.

Comment: No, JSK NS. Not that I know of, as it is a shared hosting service.

Comment: I haven't updated anything, or imported/exported anything. I've created a table and that's it.

Comment: I've fixed it. My hashNew() function is as follows.

[code]
function hashNew($str) {
return base64_encode(sha1(md5($str)));
}
[/code]

It was generating a value too big for MySQL, it seems.

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes it happens due the import/export of DBs with different versions.
I found this on google, try with this command
`mysql_upgrade --force -uroot -p`

Source: http://www.tillett.info/2012/02/17/mysql-problem-column-count-of-mysql-proc-is-wrong-expected-20-found-16-the-table-is-probably-corrupted/

If this doesn't work, try a different way to make a import/export.

Comment: Sweet - worked right away after importing some databases from ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

The error message "Column count of mysql.proc is wrong" happens if you have old pre 5.1 MySQL system tables loaded on 5.1 server. It is a configuration issue in MySQL.

You can fix the error on MySQL 5.1 server by running mysql_upgrade-command.

I'm not sure what permissions you have on the MySQL database if you are using a hosting provider.